# Redirect A subdomain To A folder in the same Subdomain using .htaccess - Browser detection language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create a conditional redirect (browser language) and rewrite for apache that accomplishes the following

redirect a subdomain to a folder of the same subdomain i.e

```
subdomain.domain.com redirects to subdomain.domain.com/es (if the browser language is setup on spanish, es or es-es)
subdomain.domain.com redirects to subdomain.domain.com/en (if the browser language is setup on english, en or en-us)
```

The Solution is

```
#Allow rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com [NC]

#For spanish redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/es/$1 [L,R=301]

#For english redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But if I type on the URL bar for example

```
subdomain.domain.com/badurl (the badurl folder dont exist)
```

The browser goto a:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/es/404.shtml
```

and says "This webpage has a redirect loop"

How I can solve this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `THE_REQUEST`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es [NC]
```

Comment: Damn! I forgot that `THE_REQUEST` is the whole request line :/